# TI synchronous buck converter went up in smoke, where do i start?

Tags: texas-instruments, troubleshooting, buck-boost, failure

I’m using a [TPSM63606RDLR](https://www.ti.com/product/TPSM63606/part-details/TPSM63606RDLR) power module device. Everything looked perfect for multiple days, but yesterday it started smoking. I did move the PCB and there are some LED strips connected externally to it but it's hard to remember what exactly happened leading to this situation. Vin is now shorted to Vout, resulting in more damage on the PCB.

*(Normal situation: Vin = 24 V, Vout = 12 V)*

What could be the root cause of the device going up in smoke?

- My first thought would be an overload or complete short from Vout to GND, but as far as I’m aware the device should be protected against this kind of fault.
- 2nd option would be a short from Vout to the Vout from a different (lower voltage) buck converter (they share the same common gnd.) The other buck converter is fine, so doesn't seem plausible.
- Maybe a short from Vout to Vin somewhere on the PCB. I don't know what this would result in.
- Maybe a problem with the input voltage. (It's from a switching Mean Well power supply and I did not switch it on/off when the fault occurred, so doesn't seem likely, I've used 5 meter cable, maybe parasitic capacitance could be a thing.)
- Configuration fault (resistors or capacitors surrounding the device not in specification I did follow the manual.)

Stating the fact the device is protected internally against some external faults, what would be a possible explanation? How could I further investigate the root cause? There is no visible damage on the PCB or components.

Comment: Is there a short from the output to ground? If so, are there any shorted capacitors across the output? You may need to remove them from the PCB to test them.

Comment: No, there is no short measured from Vout to GND. Only Vout to Vin.

I may try to remove the IC to make sure the IC is the only component creating the short from Vout to Vin.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons. If you want a serious reply, you should post a picture of the burnt PCB together with a schematic.

Comment: Basically, it could go up in smoke because of wrong Vin, or spikes through Vin, or too high current (due to a short etc), or reverse voltage, or ESD damage, or wrong components/values, or incorrectly mounted components, or poor soldering, or wrong layout... etc etc etc. The most common problems on prototypes by far would be the wrong components/values or the soldering.

Comment: Wouldn't the device be inherently protected against an overcurrent or shortcircuit situation?